# Change tooltip text color for different text parts using c#

Tags: c#, telerik, tooltip

I'm trying to show a `System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip` with colored text on a `Telerik RadControl`. Some text parts should have a different text color as others. So for example like this:

```
This text should be red
This text should be blue
Again red
Green here
```

I'm using the `RadControl.ToolTipTextNeeded()` event handler. I tried using the `ForeColor` property, but that doesn't change anything.

```
private void gvOverview_ToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, ToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)
{
    e.ToolTip.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    e.ToolTipText = "red green blue";
}
```

I also tried using HTML, but I think that's not possible. Anyway, I gave it a try.

```
private void gvOverview_ToolTipTextNeeded(object sender, ToolTipTextNeededEventArgs e)
{
    e.ToolTipText = "<font color=\"red\">red</font> <font color=\"green\">green</font> <font color=\"blue\">blue</font>";
}
```

As I expected, that didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You said `System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip` but what is `ToolTipTextNeeded` event and`ToolTipTextNeededEventArgs`?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I totally forgot, this is a Telerik control. In Telerik this event is existing. I'll add this to my question